# Cannot encrypt Realme 7 Pro running Android 13 (Project Elixir ROM)

Tags: custom-roms, kernel, disk-encryption, android-13, realme

I have Realme 7 Pro device with an unlocked bootloader and installed custom ROM:

- Project Elixir 3.8
- Android 13
- Kernel 4.14.212
- Selinux Status "Enforcing"
- Custom Recovery "OrangeFox R11.1"

The phone is showing "phone not encrypted":

[image]

I tried to follow this [XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-enable-encryption-on-a-custom-rom-which-has-it-disabled-by-default.4312447/) to make the phone encrypted with no luck. When I use the stock firmware I got it encrypted normally with "FBE Encryption", but with custom ROMs, it's not.

**Is it possible to encrypt the phone when using custom ROM? and how?** Thank you.

Comment: There's [another thread on XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-12-0-whyred-project-elixir-official-twelve-aosp.4381583/post-86213859) mentioning the encryption being broken (not supported by custom recovery) since Android 12 for Xiaomi devices.

Comment: This is Realme device not Xaiomi, and the latest OFOX recovery supports encryption now

Comment: Sorry, I mistook Realme for Redmi (Xiaomi). In addition to waiting for an answer here, I think it's better to also ask on their official support forum if possible.